# Plot pairs of all columns averages in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization

I know how to draw pair averages of columns of a dataframe:

```
def plot_mean(columns_x, columns_y):
    plt.axis([-1, 1, -1, 1])     
    plt.grid(True) 
    plt.scatter(df[columns_x].mean(), df[columns_y].mean(),
                alpha=0.4, edgecolors='w')
    plt.show()

[plot_mean(columns_x, columns_y) for columns_x in df_features.columns for columns_y in df_features.columns if columns_x != columns_y]
```

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I would like a diagram like the following pairplot but only with the averages and do not repeat the work for the columns already done:

```
# Seaborn visualization library
import seaborn as sns
# Create the default pairplot
sns.pairplot(df_features)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Try `itertools.combinations(df_features.columns)` to get all column pairs in advance if you don't want to repeat the calculated columns.